# Send an object from a spring mvc controller to a angularjs ng-init parameter

Tags: spring, angularjs, controller, jstl

i am trying to send an object from a java spring mvc controller to an angular ng-init variable. The code for my controller is the one bellow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orderStock/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView orderStockForm(HttpServletRequest req, ModelAndView model){

    //Get ep locations data list
    List<Location> epLocationList = locationService.findAllLocations();



    model.setViewName("orders/newOrderStock");
    model.addObject("epLocationList", epLocationList);


    return model;
}
```

and in my jsp file my form start like this:

```
<div class="tabContent">
<form method="post" id="newOrderStockForm" ng-init="locationData" >
```

What i am trying to do is to connect my epLocationList Object form controller with the locationData variable in some way. I am trying with jstl tags, but i haven't find any solution yet.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Initialize it in the controller rather than in ng-init

Comment: Do an ajax call to get the data and display it once it's loaded